# C# - how to put a string in the middle of the string?

Tags: c#, string

```
string a = "I have";
string b = "two apples";
```

a+b method will make it "I havetwo apples", but what if I want the result to be "I two appleshave" or anything that puts string b in the middle of string a? not at the end of it. thanks.

Comment: What have you tried, a good started would be `StringBuilder` and `String.Replace` or `String.Insert`.

Comment: Split first string and concatenate the results in the order that you like most.

Comment: So you're looking for a `Text2YodaSpeech` method?

Comment: @SJuan76: That would be the painful way to do it if the standard library didn't already provide a mechanism for you...

Comment: The best way depends highly on where you want to put the 2nd string in the first IMO. If you want it in a whitespace, all whitespaces, or at a specific index, or at the median, there are different ways to do that efficiently.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault: He gave an example, that makes it pretty clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You insert it into the string.  The documentation is quite clear on this...

```
var combined = someString.Insert(startIdx, otherString)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Take your pick:**

```
a + " " + b 
(a+b).Insert(6, " ")
string.Join(" ", a, b)
string.Format("{0} {1}", a,b)
$"{a} {b}"

"I {0}have".Format(b)
a.Insert(2,b)
```

**Documentation:**

[`String.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx)
[`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)
[`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)
[`Interpolation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: OP don't want to include a white space between the two words like aaaa bbb, he wants aabbbaa

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault which is why I included two examples that do that... but his sample cries out that whitespace is what he'll ultimately use this for.

Comment: was talking about the examples that were doing `a + " " + b`, which is totally not what OP was asking, you had originally

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx) method like;

```
string a = "I have";
string b = "two apples";

string[] array = a.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.WriteLine(array[0] + " " + b + array[1]); //I two appleshave
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/VK9x9h).

**EDIT**: As Ed S. *[mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17116657/447156)*, you can use [`String.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx) method also like;

```
string a = "I have";
string b = "two apples";
Console.WriteLine(a.Insert(a.IndexOf(' ') + 1, b)); //I two appleshave
```